# tried to access the data via axios but Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: reactjs

I was working over react and made a request using axios but in the browser it shows "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check" i had installed the corx extension but still getting the same error

Comment: Please post some code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `create-react-app` you can try defining a `proxy` property in your `package.json` file and give the url to your api server, something like

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000".
```

This will proxy your api calls through the express server provided within create-react-app without the need for any CORS configuration in your browser

**Note** : This can be only used in your local environment and for production setup, you should try alternate approaches by configuring CORS setting in the API server or hosting the UI and API applications under the same hostname